# Selenium Automatically Closes Chrome Console (attached or window)

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

When debugging in Chrome I expierence that Selenium is automatically closing the console window/tab (F12) even if it resides in its own detached window.

This really distrubt or even make driving a debugging session with selenium impossible.

Is there a known workaround or is this a feature I have to live with?

Comment: Selenium is fundamentally different in the way it instantiates browsers.Why do you want to debug a selenium session ? Cant you just reproduce the scenario and check manually.

Comment: Always asking a question turns out the question whether it makes sense... . I just want to trigger events and see what happens. I can do this by adding javascript via the console but I cant do this with mouse or keyboard since a focus event happens before and chrome debugging capabilities are limited. So if I for instance click with the mouse the debugger comes up and I can not type a key. Simple as that. And adding five lines of code everytime... it does not makes sense.